# Odd behavior when changing CSS Grid elements' order with a transition, how to fix that?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-grid

I want to change the order of elements inside a grid container by clicking on a button. I simply gave the child element a transition property and the result was so strange.

First of all, the timing is completely wrong between the transition's timing value and the actual time that it takes to achieve that, also it happens on many stages in a strange and random order, finally and most importantly there is no transition effect or what so ever.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```js
function changeOrder(){
var elmnts = document.querySelectorAll(".container>div");
  elmnts.forEach((item, i) => {
   item.style.order = 5 - i;
  });
}
```

```css
.container{
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 150px);
  grid-column-gap: 4px;
  grid-row-gap: 24px;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 25px;
}
.container > div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: order 20s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="changeOrder()">Change order</button>
```

So is there a way to achieve that, to give a sense of motion when the element moves from a position to another due to changes in its order value?

Comment: The order property cannot be transitioned in that fashion

Comment: You would need to calculate the actual position of each element and the adjust for their new order and position. That will require a lot of javascript

Comment: It's a shame that we can't animate order property, instead, I have to do it now with (Transform-Translate) just for the sake of giving it proper and smooth motion.

Comment: And it's really a lot of work.